# invalid argument value in python tkinter button

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem passing an argument to a function that is called after clicking a token in tkinter.
m and n are integers from 2 to 9.

When I click the button, it prints the largest value, i.e. if m = 9 and n = 9 then the function `l_click` only prints the highest value, i.e. in this case 9 and 9.

I want the value 0.0 to be displayed after clicking the button in the grid with m = 0 and n = 0. Please help

```
def l_click():
    print("x",x)
    print("y",y)


 for x in range(m):
    pole.append([])
    for y in range(n):

        pole[x].append(Button(game_window,width='20',height='20',image=photo,command=l_click))
        pole[x][y].bind('<Button-3>',r_click)
        pole[x][y].grid(row=x, column=y)
```

Comment: Change `command=l_click` to `.bind("<Button-1>", ...` and use `event.widget.grid_info(...`. Read up on [`grid_info()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_info-method)

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is with regards to variable scopes in python. The issue is `l_click()` prints only the value of the variable at that time. Since you would like the value during the declaration, pass them as arguments to the `l_click` function using a lambda expression.
The code block to reflect this would be something like:

```
def l_click(x, y):
    print("x",x)
    print("y",y)

for x in range(m):
    pole.append([])
    for y in range(n):
        pole[x].append(Button(game_window,width='20',height='20',image=photo,command=lambda x=x, y=y: l_click(x, y)))
        pole[x][y].bind('<Button-3>', r_click)
        pole[x][y].grid(row=x, column=y)
```